# Vscode vim : yank to next blank space

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode vim. I'm working with a lot of css styles that look like:

```
<v-layout align-start justify-center row fill-height>
```

if I put my curser on v in v-layout and yank , only v is saved . How do I efficiently yank to the first blank character, so that I save "v-layout" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the **t** motion.

```
yt<space>
```

Verbally, I think of this as **y**ank un**t**il the next space.

You could also do

```
yE
```

For **y**ank to **E**nd of the current WORD.